# Can I declare and use variables "inline" in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

can I do something like this pseudo code and use variables *inline* within the select? I know that in this case variables are not needed, I have a more complex use case in mind.

```
select 
t.foo,
t.bar,

var var1 = 100 + t.foo + t.bar;
(return var1) as result

from table t
where 1=1 and ...
```

cheers

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that you couldn't achieve through `select t.foo, t.bar, 100+t.foo+t.bar as result from table t …`?

Comment: No, you cannot. Please research about SQL syntax before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Oracle does not support your syntax:

> ```
> select t.foo,
>        t.bar,
>        var var1 = 100 + t.foo + t.bar;
>        (return var1) as result
> from   table t
> where  1=1
> and    ...
> ```

The full syntax for the `SELECT` statement is [documented here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm) and that syntax is not included. Particularly:

> `SELECT` syntax:
>
> [image: SELECT syntax]
>
> `select_list` syntax:
>
> [image: select_list syntax]